# Superset cannot connect to my MSSQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

After installing Superset (open source software from Airbnb) on my virtual machine (RHEL, Linux 7.2-11), I cannot add my MSSQL database in the configuration page.

Menu->Sources->Databases->Add

In the SQLAlchemy URI field, I entered :

```
mssql+pymssql://user:password@host:port/database
```

Obviously, with my user, password, host, port and database name.

But when I click "Test Connection" I have the following error :

```
ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!
The error message returned was:
(pymssql.OperationalError) (18456, 'DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\
DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\
Adaptive Server connection failed (host:port)')"}
```

I already installed the pymssql package and I do not really know where this error could come from.

I tried to follow these tutorials but, maybe I'm doing it wrong:

http://airbnb.io/superset/installation.html

http://airbnb.io/superset/tutorial.html#connecting-to-a-new-database

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is the following:

```
mssql+pymssql://user:pass@address.of.db/?charset=utf8
```

However, I didn't manage to define a database using this syntax, and in turn couldn't define/find the available tables.

Comment: Thank you Dror, but it also failed. I am sure there is a problem of driver. I need an equivalent of jTDS driver for python to connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication, from my RHEL virtual machine. Maybe you've heard about such a driver ?

Comment: I don't know... What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 2.7-11

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can further help :(

Answer (score 0):

I was also having problem to connect with MSSQL. I was on macOS Catalina. I took the following steps, and it worked:

1. brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. pip install pyodbc
3. mssql+pyodbc://UserName:Password@HostIP,Port/DBName?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Mentioning of 'driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' in the end is important. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51266453/13150101)

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to install the MSSQL driver first, which I did with:

```
docker exec -it superset_app bash -c 'pip install pymssql'
```

In the Superset UI, I was then able to connect to the database by choosing the "Microsoft SQL Server" database and setting the SQLALCHEMY URI:

```
mssql+pymssql://username:password@host:port/dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create an URL like this in python; this works fine in Apache Superset with sqlalchemy for SQL Server with ODBC 18 & PyODBC

Note: edit the driver according to your system

This works for Serverless e.g. Azure Sql

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

connection_url = sa.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD,
    host=SERVER,
    database=DATABASE,
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
        "Encrypt": "yes",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes",
        "Remote Query Timeout": '300'       
    },
)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
print(connection_url.render_as_string(hide_password=False))
```

or This is for Sql sever

```
mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER={SERVER};DATABASE={DATABASE};UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD};TrustServerCertificate=yes
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try mssql://user:password@host:port/database

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried it and I have this error now :
"ERROR:{"error":"Connection failed!
The error message returned was : 
(pyodbc.Error)('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')"}"

Previously I installed the ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-linux). And I also installed pyodbc. Thank you again :)

Comment: You need to specify the driver name in the connection string. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections