# How to Connect to SQL from R Studio

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi, dbplyr

I use *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio* on Windows 10 to connect to the following database and this is what the login screen looks like:

```
Server Type:      Database Engine
Server Name:      sqlmiprod.b298745190e.database.windows.net
Authentication:   SQL Server Authentication
Login:            my_user_id
Password:         my_password
```

[This recent R Studio article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/214510788-Setting-up-R-to-connect-to-SQL-Server-) offers an easy way to connect to SQL Servers from R Studio using the following:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "[your driver's name]",
                      Server   = "[your server's path]",
                      Database = "[your database's name]",
                      UID      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                      Port     = 1433)
```

I have two questions

1. What should I use as `"[your driver's name]"`?
2. What should I use as `"[your database's name]"`?

The server path I'll use is `sqlmiprod.b298745190e.database.windows.net` (from above) and I'll leave the port at `1433`. If that's wrong please let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606832/r-unixodbcdriver-managercant-open-lib-sql-server-file-not-found/51266453#51266453 please chek the answer of your question

Comment: I use a similar setup and had to make a System Data Source in Microsoft ODBC Source Administrator. Once that was good to go all I had to do to connect is `con <- dbConnect(odbc(), "db_name")` and I'm good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Driver

From @Zaynul's comment and my own experience, the driver field is a text string with the name of the ODBC driver. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440008/differences-between-drivers-for-odbc-drivers) contains more details on this.

You probably want someting like:

- `Driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'` (from @Zaynul's comment)
- `Driver = 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server'` (from my own context)

## Database

The default database you want to connect to. Roughly equivalent to starting an SQL script with

```
USE my_database
GO
```

If all your work will be within a single database then puts its name here.

In some contexts you should be able to leave this blank, but you then have to use the `in_schema` command to add the database name every time you connect to a table.

If you are working across multiple databases, I recommend putting the name of one database in, and then using the `in_schema` command to specify the database at every point of connection.

Example using the `in_schema` command ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289494/how-do-i-access-nested-sql-tables-in-r/58293276#58293276)):

```
df = tbl(con, from = in_schema('database.schema', 'table'))
```

Though I have not tried it, if you do not have a schema then

```
df = tbl(con, from = in_schema('database', 'table'))
```

Should also work (I've been using this hack without issue for a while).

Comment: Importantly, OP needs to download an [MSSQL ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) beforehand. This is a physical software that serves as middle man between application layer and databases. ODBC is a technology used beyond R.